# How to find monotonous sequence along with taking into account sequence restart on reaching the maximum

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table say dt

```
name <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v")
score <- c(42, 82, 43, 32,47,48, 49, 50, 54, 59, 76, 09, 13, 88, 91, 99, 04, 06, 08, 12, 14, 15)
class <- c("c1", "c1", "c1", "c1","c1", "c1", "c1", "c2", "c2", "c2", "c3", "c3", "c3", "c3","c3", "c3", "c3", "c3", "c3", "c3", "c3" ,"c3")
dt <- data.table(name, score, class)
```

it looks like:

```
> dt
    name score class
 1:    a    42    c1
 2:    b    82    c1
 3:    c    43    c1
 4:    d    32    c1
 5:    e    47    c1
 6:    f    48    c1
 7:    g    49    c1
 8:    h    50    c2
 9:    i    54    c2
10:    j    59    c2
11:    k    76    c3
12:    l     9    c3
13:    m    13    c3
14:    n    88    c3
15:    o    91    c3
16:    p    99    c3
17:    q     4    c3
18:    r     6    c3
19:    s     8    c3
20:    t    12    c3
21:    u    14    c3
22:    v    15    c3
```

I only require those records which follow a monotonous sequence of the score for each class. in this case only records with score 42, 43,47,48 49 for class c1, records with score 50, 54, 59 for class c2.

In class "c3" records with score 76,88,91,99,04,06,08,12, 14, 15. Here the sequence have reached the maximum(99) and then have restarted. Scores 09 and 13 in class "c3" were out of the monotonous sequence hence needed to be removed.

I want to remove those records where score mentioned are not in sequence for each of the class c1, c2, c3. There are in total 1 million records.

There can be at maximum 3 consecutive out of sequence scores for a given class.

the final output must look like.

```
> dt
    name score class
 1:    a    42    c1
 2:    c    43    c1
 3:    e    47    c1
 4:    f    48    c1
 5:    g    49    c1
 6:    h    50    c2
 7:    i    54    c2
 8:    j    59    c2
 9:    k    76    c3
10:    n    88    c3
11:    o    91    c3
12:    p    99    c3
13:    q     4    c3
14:    r     6    c3
15:    s     8    c3
16:    t    12    c3
17:    u    14    c3
18:    v    15    c3
```

In order to find monotonous sequence I have tried:

```
dt <- dt[, .SD[score == cummax(score)],class]
```

but this is also removing the sequence which are restarting after reaching the maximum value. How to do this.

Comment: Are the values in score column always in between 1-99?

Comment: no the score value in general go upto a maximum of 999999, but for example here I took is as 99

Comment: You'll have to explain why row 2 is "not in sequence" and  also what happened to row 8.

Comment: row 2 is not in sequence as it is followed by more than 3 in sequence scores, row 8 is not in sequence because the value is diverting very much from the normal sequence, hence an outlier.

Comment: row 8 though is the first score in class 2 , though as the value is very less that the normal sequence, hence that too have to taken as out of sequence.

Comment: though I can create some other logic for row 8 later, so if leaving row 8 other portions can be looked that too would be also very helpful

Comment: Oh and how do you expect others to know about these aspects? And how should we judge whether something is far from a sequence? You're missing essential details

Comment: I will write some other data cleaning logic later and will edit the code as per that, so I am replacing the row 8 data from 28 to 50 , so remove this complexity, if that is okay

Comment: There are two other questions which appear to be nearly identical (except for the data): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030594/finding-monotonous-sequence-along-with-taking-sequence-restart-on-reaching-maxim and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44094497/removing-an-out-of-sequence-number-from-a-column-in-data-table-in-r

Answer (score 3):

The `cummax` idea is very good - you just need some modifications:

```
dt[, keep := score >= cummax(shift(score, fill = first(score))), 
     by = .(class, rleid(score == 99))]
```

Or, perhaps a better approach would be

```
dt[dt[, .I[score == cummax(score)], by = list(class, rleid(score == 99))]$V1]
```

Comment: but this is also removing all other scores is the out of sequence is occurring at the beginning. say if in class "c1" 82 is written in records 2 then all the following records will be marked as FALSE. at the maximum  there can be only 3 continuous out of sequence scores.

Comment: @archit As far as I can tell, this gives the output asked for in the question...? If you need to add some additional explanation, it's best to edit it into the question. Of course, editing to invalidate an answer is not great etiquette here, unless docendo is fine with it.

Comment: @docendo, I am editing the question to make the data representative of what is desired .

Comment: @docendo, I have edited the question and corrected the data.

Comment: can anyone comment how to proceed

Comment: @Architgupta, you should probably unaccept my answer if it doesn't solve your (edited) question