# Finding monotonous sequence along with taking sequence restart on reaching maximum into account

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data.table say dt

```
name <- letters[1:22]
score <- c(42, 82, 43, 32, 47, 48, 49, 50, 54, 59, 
           76, 9, 13, 88, 91, 99, 4, 6, 8, 12, 14, 15)
class <- rep(c('c1', 'c2', 'c3'), c(7, 3, 12))
dt <- data.table(name, score, class)
```

it looks like:

```
> dt
    name score class
 1:    a    42    c1
 2:    b    82    c1
 3:    c    43    c1
 4:    d    32    c1
 5:    e    47    c1
 6:    f    48    c1
 7:    g    49    c1
 8:    h    50    c2
 9:    i    54    c2
10:    j    59    c2
11:    k    76    c3
12:    l     9    c3
13:    m    13    c3
14:    n    88    c3
15:    o    91    c3
16:    p    99    c3
17:    q     4    c3
18:    r     6    c3
19:    s     8    c3
20:    t    12    c3
21:    u    14    c3
22:    v    15    c3
```

I only require those records which follow a monotonous sequence of the score for each class. in this case only records with score 42, 43,47,48 49 for class c1, There can be at maximum 3 consecutive out of sequence scores for a given class.  row 2(score = 82) is hence also a out of sequence score.

Records with score 50, 54, 59 for class c2.

In class "c3" records with score 76,88,91,99,04,06,08,12, 14, 15. Here the sequence have reached the maximum(99) and then have restarted. Scores 09 and 13 in class "c3" were out of the monotonous sequence hence needed to be removed.

I want to remove those records where score mentioned are not in sequence for each of the class c1, c2, c3. There are in total 1 million records.

The final output must look like.

```
> dt
    name score class
 1:    a    42    c1
 2:    c    43    c1
 3:    e    47    c1
 4:    f    48    c1
 5:    g    49    c1
 6:    h    50    c2
 7:    i    54    c2
 8:    j    59    c2
 9:    k    76    c3
10:    n    88    c3
11:    o    91    c3
12:    p    99    c3
13:    q     4    c3
14:    r     6    c3
15:    s     8    c3
16:    t    12    c3
17:    u    14    c3
18:    v    15    c3
```

In order to find monotonous sequence I have tried:

```
dt <- dt[, .SD[score == cummax(score)],class]
```

but this is also removing the sequence which are restarting after reaching the maximum value.

In actual the maximum of sequence restart if 999999, though for this example I have taken maximum as 99. How can I do this.

Comment: I'm not sure your condition for inclusion is well-defined. Could you try and be more explicit?

Comment: the sequence must be monotonous and I need to remove any out-of-sequence from between and at the same time also have to take care of sequence restart

Comment: dt[, keep := score >= cummax(shift(score, fill = first(score))), 
     by = .(class, rleid(score == 99))]                                                                                    this is taking care of the monotonous sequence also, maximization condition but it is removing row 3 to row 7 from class c1, as score 82 is mentioned before, though that is out of sequence and must be removed

Comment: For example, how do we know to exclude 76 from `c3`? What's the condition for picking the lowest element of the sequence?

Comment: first element for each class is the lowest, else we look at the few previous seq of the previous class

Comment: You might want to merge your accounts (to combine the question lists, rep, etc.): http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: So the sequence can only reach 99 (or 999999 in the real data) and restart, but can not restart from the middle, like c3, 76-restart-9-13?

Comment: the maximum value can be 99

Comment: There are two other questions which appear to be nearly identical (except for the data): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027088/how-to-find-monotonous-sequence-along-with-taking-into-account-sequence-restart and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44094497/removing-an-out-of-sequence-number-from-a-column-in-data-table-in-r

Answer (score 0):

This could mostly be done using `dplyr`

```
dts <- dt %>% 
       group_by(class) %>% 
       mutate(f = ifelse( (score - lead(score) > 0 & lag(score) - score <0) | 
                          (score - lead(score) < 0 & lag(score) - score > 0) , 1, 0)) %>%
       mutate(f = ifelse(is.na(f), 0, f)) %>%
       mutate(g = ifelse((lead(f) == 1 & f == 1)| (lag(f) == 1 & f == 1 ), 2, 0) )) %>%
       filter(f + g != 1)
```

As I said, this will mostly get you there. The problem with this is you will get 19 observations (retaining `id = m`) as opposed to 18. What you can do is re-run this on `dts` to eliminate `id = m`.  Or if this is a subset of a larger set, you can use `for` or `while` loops. The reason for this is because the `lead` and `lag` function only check one index above and below.

Another option is an old school technique known as a push-pop technique, but I would stay away from that.