# Removing an out of sequence number from a column in data.table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data table dt, with three columns nm, seqn and obj

```
> nm <- letters[1:22]
> seqn <- c(32,36, 86,45 , 47, 48, 49,
+            52, 54, 59, 
+            66, 9, 69, 74, 81, 88, 90, 91, 93, 94, 95, 97)
> obj <- rep(c('c1', 'c2', 'c3'), c(7, 3, 12))
> dt <- data.table(nm, seqn, obj)
> dt
    nm seqn obj
 1:  a   32  c1
 2:  b   36  c1
 3:  c   86  c1
 4:  d   45  c1
 5:  e   47  c1
 6:  f   48  c1
 7:  g   49  c1
 8:  h   52  c2
 9:  i   54  c2
10:  j   59  c2
11:  k   66  c3
12:  l    9  c3
13:  m   69  c3
14:  n   74  c3
15:  o   81  c3
16:  p   88  c3
17:  q   90  c3
18:  r   91  c3
19:  s   93  c3
20:  t   94  c3
21:  u   95  c3
22:  v   97  c3
```

I want to get a monotonous sequence of "seqn" for each "obj" group. I want to remove the out of sequence numbers like 86(record 3) in case of obj "c1" (* here 86 is a big number while the usual series of small monotonous seqn numbers) and in case of obj "c3" , I want to remove seqn 9. (record 12) (* here 9 is a small number in monotonous seqn of big numbers ).

How can I do this with data.table/dataframe.

Comment: My logic is to remove a larger number when it is preceded and followed by smaller numbers and removing a smaller number when it is preceded and followed by larger numbers. How can that be done ?

Comment: There are two other questions which appear to be nearly identical (except for the data): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030594/finding-monotonous-sequence-along-with-taking-sequence-restart-on-reaching-maxim and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027088/how-to-find-monotonous-sequence-along-with-taking-into-account-sequence-restart

Comment: @Uwe: i thought so to, but they actually have a "restart on max" which makes it easier and not transferable. @Ravi: you can do: `dt[!((seqn < shift(seqn, fill=0, type = "lag") | seqn > shift(seqn, fill=999, type = "lead")) & shift(seqn, fill=999, type = "lead") > shift(seqn, fill=999, type = "lag")), .SD, by = obj][]`

Comment: @BigDataScientist, I am getting an error "Error in `[.data.frame`(dt, !((seqn < shift(seqn, fill = 0, type = "lag") |  : 
  unused argument (by = obj)"

Comment: seems like you dont use a data table. make sure to clear your environment, reload the data as you posted it, check that is of type data table and then run the code in my comment,...for me that works.

Comment: Thank you @BigDataScientist, it worked for me now

Comment: @BigDataScientist The OP has just disclosed in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44094497/removing-an-out-of-sequence-number-from-a-column-in-data-table-in-r#comment75362243_44159820) 2 additional requirements including restart after reaching maximum and elimination of up to three consecutive out-of-sequence values. This makes his question to full duplicates of the two other linked Q, IMO.

Comment: oh boy. Sry to read that. You are totally right. Thats really a waste, especially after the other questions were linked it should have been noted.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another `data.table` solution which is different from the solution suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44094497/removing-an-out-of-sequence-number-from-a-column-in-data-table-in-r#comment75235407_44094497).

The OP has requested *to get a monotonous sequence of `seqn` for each `obj` group*. In addition, the OP has [detailed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44094497/removing-an-out-of-sequence-number-from-a-column-in-data-table-in-r/44159820#comment75210640_44094497) that he needs *to remove a larger number when it is preceeded and followed by smaller numbers and removing a smaller number when it is preceeded and followed by larger numbers.* Although not stated explicitely, it can be concluded from the supplied data that the OP is referring to monotonically *increasing* sequences.

```
library(data.table)
DT[-DT[, .I[which(xor(
  shift(seqn) < shift(seqn, type = "lead"),
  between(seqn, shift(seqn), shift(seqn, type = "lead"))
))], by = obj]$V1]
#    nm seqn obj
# 1:  a   32  c1
# 2:  b   36  c1
# 3:  d   45  c1
# 4:  e   47  c1
# 5:  f   48  c1
# 6:  g   49  c1
# 7:  h   52  c2
# 8:  i   54  c2
# 9:  j   59  c2
#10:  k   66  c3
#11:  m   69  c3
#12:  n   74  c3
#13:  o   81  c3
#14:  p   88  c3
#15:  q   90  c3
#16:  r   91  c3
#17:  s   93  c3
#18:  t   94  c3
#19:  u   95  c3
#20:  v   97  c3
```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
nm <- letters[1:22]
seqn <- c(32,36, 86,45 , 47, 48, 49, 52, 54, 59, 
          66, 9, 69, 74, 81, 88, 90, 91, 93, 94, 95, 97)
obj <- rep(c('c1', 'c2', 'c3'), c(7, 3, 12))
DT <- data.table(nm, seqn, obj)
```

---

#### Violation of monotonicity at begin and end of each sequence

The above approach can be enhanced to cover edge cases where the monotonicity is violated at begin or end of each sequence, i.e., for each `obj` group.

For example:

```
seqn <- c(32,36, 86, 45, 47, -48, 49, 52, 54, 59, 
          66, 9, 13, 74, 81, 88, 90, 91, 93, 94, 95, 11)
(DT <- data.table(nm, seqn, obj))
#    nm seqn obj
# 1:  a   32  c1
# 2:  b   36  c1
# 3:  c   86  c1
# 4:  d   45  c1
# 5:  e   47  c1
# 6:  f   48  c1
# 7:  g   49  c1
# 8:  h   52  c2
# 9:  i   54  c2
#10:  j   59  c2
#11:  k   66  c3
#12:  l    9  c3
#13:  m   13  c3
#14:  n   74  c3
#15:  o   81  c3
#16:  p   88  c3
#17:  q   90  c3
#18:  r   91  c3
#19:  s   93  c3
#20:  t   94  c3
#21:  u   95  c3
#22:  v   11  c3
#    nm seqn obj
```

Note that `DT` has been changed in rows 13 and 22. Now, the first and the last elements of `obj` group `c3` have become "outliers". The first element 66 is larger than the next two elements 9 and 13, and the last element 11 is lower than the preceeding element 95. So, the monotonically increasing sequence starts with 9 and ends with 95, and the elements 66 and 11 have to be removed.

This is achieved by simply padding each sequence with a leading `-Inf` and a trailing `+Inf`. No other change to the code is required except that the result has to be shifted back to pick the correct row number:

```
DT[-DT[, {seqn <- c(-Inf, seqn, +Inf); .I[which(shift(xor(
  shift(seqn) < shift(seqn, type = "lead"),
  between(seqn, shift(seqn), shift(seqn, type = "lead"))
), type = "lead"))]}, by = obj]$V1]
#    nm seqn obj
# 1:  a   32  c1
# 2:  b   36  c1
# 3:  d   45  c1
# 4:  e   47  c1
# 5:  f   48  c1
# 6:  g   49  c1
# 7:  h   52  c2
# 8:  i   54  c2
# 9:  j   59  c2
#10:  l    9  c3
#11:  m   13  c3
#12:  n   74  c3
#13:  o   81  c3
#14:  p   88  c3
#15:  q   90  c3
#16:  r   91  c3
#17:  s   93  c3
#18:  t   94  c3
#19:  u   95  c3
```

Comment: I don't undersand this, it is also removing all the observations when obj = c2

Comment: @RaviMishra Misplaced minus sign. Code is fixed now.

Comment: this code is failing to remove the seqn 9, for the obj c3, if 69 is replaced by other seqn , say 13, please refer to the following data in next comment

Comment: seqn <- c(32,36, 86,45, 47, 48, 49,
                        52, 54, 59, 
                        66, 9, 13, 74, 81, 88, 90, 91, 93, 94, 95, 97)

Comment: in the above case for seqn values, 9 must also be removed as that is between two bigger numbers, 66 and 13 but is is not removed

Comment: @RaviMishra In this case, it's the 66 which should be removed, as 9, 13, 74, 81, etc form a monotonously increasing sequence.

Comment: but that too is not removed on running the code, and monotonous sequence should be considered taking into account the first sequence value and not from between. so 66 must be the first seqn

Comment: Is the assumption correct that you have _only one_ monotonically increasing sequence per  `obj` group?

Comment: yes, except when the numbers restart on reaching near the maximum(100). at the same time there can be at maximum 3 consecutive out of sequence numbers which have to removed, for example if the sequence is like 42, 45, 46, 48, 2,5,7, 50, 52, 57, 47, 60 , 68, 72 then in this case 2 ,5, 7, 47 are out of sequence numbers and should be removed.

Comment: That is a nasty surprise! You are telling me now - after I've spent hours on working on an answer for _you_ - that there are additional requirements which you have failed to describe in your initial question?

Comment: the above solution is throwing an error : 
`Error: expecting a single value`